# Maintain comments while writing config file in Python

Tags: python, parsing, config

I have a Dictionary like this

```
dictvalues = {'NAME':'Zara', 'SUBJECT':'English', 'CLASS ':'First'}
```

I have a config.ini like this

```
[OPTIONS]

;the following specifies the name of student
NAME = "Zara"
;The following specifies Subject
SUBJECT = "MATHS"

;The Following specifies the Marks

MARKS = "55"
```

I want to update my config.ini file based on the dictionary

```
;the following specifies the name of student
NAME = "Zara"
;The following specifies Subject
SUBJECT = "MATHS"

;The Following specifies the Marks

MARKS = "55"


CLASS = "FIRST"
```

The following code removes the comments.Which are required.

```
import ConfigParser

data = {'NAME': 'Zara', 'SUBJECT': 'English', 'CLASS': 'First'}

Config = ConfigParser.ConfigParser()
Config.optionxform = str
Config.read("config.ini")


for section in Config.sections():
    for key in data.keys():
        Config.set(section, key,'"{}"'.format(data[key]))

with open("config.ini", 'w+') as f:
    Config.write(f)
```

Comment: As far as I can see, the ConfigParser module just throws away comments (and blank lines), so it is not going to be of much use if you need to retain the comments. It does track line numbers, but only uses the information to produce error messages; it does not record the line number at which an option was defined, eliminating the naive approach to rereading the file and replacing the line(s) at which the options were defined with new option lines. Your best bet might be to write your own config file parser using PLY or some other python parser generator, but that's a non-trivial task, too.

Answer (score 0):

If you will define your dictionary with `"` your output should be as expected:

```
 data = {'NAME': '"Zara"', 'SUBJECT': '"English"', 'CLASS': '"First"'}
```

Comment: Can't do that as "data" it is an input to my function

Comment: i mean to say data is an argument to my function

Comment: @user2591307 You can still add the `"`: `"{}".format(data[key])`